# Linear transformation $End(V)\rightarrow\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that V is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ of
dimension $dimV\geq2$. Give an example of a linear map $\Phi: End(V)\rightarrow\mathbb R$ whose kernel DOES NOT contain any projections of rank one.

Comment: Maybe the trace?

Comment: Why the trace ?

Comment: Well the trace is a linear map from $\operatorname{End}V$ onto $\mathbb R$. And if $P$ is a projection onto a $1$-dimensional subspace,generated by the vector $(a,b,c)$ then $\operatorname{tr}(P) = a^2+b^2+c^2 $.